# PDF prints correctly on every browser, exept for firefox

Tags: css, vue.js, pdf, browser, laravel-blade

I'm working on a pdf for a site, it works correctly, I am almost finishing it, but I noticed that when I open in firefox (I usually just use brave), I have no lines applied to my pdf, I tried some style changes but I don't seem able to find out what is wrong.
I will provide screenshoots and parts of code here:
[How it's supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnOO5.png)
[How it's looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBIS0.png)
My css:

```
    <style>
            table {
                page-break-inside: auto;
            }            
            tr {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: auto;
            }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        header {
            padding: 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        header h1 {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 30px;
            flex: 1;
        }

        header p {
            margin: 5px 0;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        header img {
            height: 60px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .tables {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        .tables td {
            border: 0px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .td60 {
            width: 60%;
        }

        .td20 {
            width: 20%;
        }

        .td40 {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .td100 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
        }
        .page-break-before {
            page-break-before: always;
        }

        .td-questions {
            border-top: none;
        }

        .medsTable {
            height: 16px;
            width: 33%;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .medsTable2 {
            border-left: 0;
        }

        .medsTable3 {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        .medsTableTop {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-top: 0;
        }

        .medsTableTop2 {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 0;
            border-top: 0;

        }
        .signatureNames {
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .signatureLines {
            margin-left: 45px;
            width: 350px;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            height: 8px;
        }
        .tableMeds {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-top: 0;
        }
        .logos {
            height: 80px; 
            width: 80px;
        }
        .w50 {
            width: 50%
        }
        .fl {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
```

I tried finding any unclosed tags in the code, any misspells, any errors on the typing, but I was not able to solve the issue. If someone needs to see more of the code I'll be happy to provide it.

Also, this is all I have on my console:

```
A cookie particionada ou o acesso ao armazenamento foi fornecido para “data:application/pdf;base64,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…

Warning: getPdfFilenameFromUrl: ignore "data:"-URL for performance reasons. pdf.js:393:13
PDF 075378a9f9e51e230f602d3f86a24b5e [1.4 Qt 4.8.7 / wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4] (PDF.js: 3.8.110 [88111e1b2]) viewer.js:1491:13
downloadable font: OS/2: Adjusting head.macStyle (regular) to match fsSelection (font-family: "g_d0_f2" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: (invalid URI)
```

My code (complete):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Anamnese{{ $data->id }}</title>

    <style>
            table {
                page-break-inside: auto;
            }            
            tr {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: auto;
            }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        header {
            padding: 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        header h1 {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 30px;
            flex: 1;
        }

        header p {
            margin: 5px 0;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        header img {
            height: 60px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .tables {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        .tables td {
            border: 0px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .td60 {
            width: 60%;
        }

        .td20 {
            width: 20%;
        }

        .td40 {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .td100 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
        }
        .page-break-before {
            page-break-before: always;
        }

        .td-questions {
            border-top: none;
        }

        .medsTable {
            height: 16px;
            width: 33%;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .medsTable2 {
            border-left: 0;
        }

        .medsTable3 {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        .medsTableTop {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-top: 0;
        }

        .medsTableTop2 {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 0;
            border-top: 0;

        }
        .signatureNames {
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .signatureLines {
            margin-left: 45px;
            width: 350px;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            height: 8px;
        }
        .tableMeds {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-top: 0;
        }
        .logos {
            height: 80px; 
            width: 80px;
        }
        .w50 {
            width: 50%
        }
        .fl {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="fl">
                    @if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->company->logo)
                        <img class="logos"
                            src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents(Auth::user()->company->logo->url)) }}">
                    @else
                        <img class="logos"
                            src="{{ public_path('images/dentalSigoLogo/logo.png') }}" alt="">
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td class="fl">
                    <h4>Anamnese - Ficha n.º {{ $data->id }}</h4>
                </td>
                <td class="td20" style="text-align: end;">
                    <p class="no-wrap">Paciente: {{ $data->user->name }}</p>
                    <p class="no-wrap">Data: {{ date('d/m/Y') }}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </header>


    <table class="tables">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Sexo: {{ $data->user->gender === 'MALE' ? 'Masculino' : ($data->user->gender === 'FEMALE' ? 'Feminino' : 'Indefinido') }}
            </td>

            <td>
                Data de Nasc.: {{ $data->user->birthday->format('d/m/Y') }}
            </td>
            <td class="td-right">
                Idade:
                @php
                    $currentDate = now();
                    $age = $currentDate->diffInYears($data->user->birthday);
                    echo $age;
                @endphp
            </td>
        </tr>


        @if ($data->user->responsibles && $data->user->responsibles->isNotEmpty())
            @foreach ($data->user->responsibles as $responsibles)
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Responsável:
                    @foreach ($data->user->responsibles as $responsible)
                        {{ $responsible['name'] }}
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        @endif
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: none">
                Está fazendo algum tratamento médico?
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border-top: none">
                Qual:
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                Faz uso de algum medicamento?
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    {{-- CRIAR MODELO DE RESPOSTAS PARA AS LINHAS ENTRE COMENTÁRIOS --}}
    <table class="tables tableMeds">
        <tr>
            <td class="medsTableTop">
                Nome
            </td>
            <td class="medsTableTop2">
                Dosagem
            </td>
            <td class="medsTableTop2">
                Tempo de Uso
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="medsTable"></td>
            <td class="medsTable2"></td>
            <td class="medsTable2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="medsTable"></td>
            <td class="medsTable2"></td>
            <td class="medsTable2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="medsTable"></td>
            <td class="medsTable2"></td>
            <td class="medsTable2"></td>
        </tr>
        @forelse ($data->questions as $key => $question)
            @if ($question['type'] === 'RADIO')
                <table class="tables">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td100">{{ $key + 1 }}.
                            @if (isset($question['alert']) && $question['alert'] === true)
                                <span style="margin-left: 10px;">
                                    <img 
                                    src="{{ public_path('images/pdf/exclamation.png') }}"
                                    alt="">
                                </span>
                            @endif
                            {{ $question['question'] }}
                        </td>
                        @if ($question['radio_answer'] === true)
                            <td class="td20">
                                Sim(X)
                            </td>
                        @endif
                        @if ($question['radio_answer'] === false)
                            <td class="td20">
                                Não(X)
                            </td>
                        @endif
                    </tr>
                </table>
            @elseif ($question['type'] === 'TEXT')
                <table class="tables">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td100">{{ $key + 1 }}.
                            @if (isset($question['alert']) && $question['alert'] === true)
                                <span style="margin-left: 10px;">
                                    <img 
                                    src="{{ public_path('images/pdf/exclamation.png') }}"
                                    alt="">
                                </span>
                            @endif
                            {{ $question['question'] }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td100"> {{ $question['text_answer'] }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                @elseif ($question['type'] === 'RADIO_TEXT')
                <table class="tables">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td100">{{ $key + 1 }}.
                            @if (isset($question['alert']) && $question['alert'] === true)
                                <span style="margin-left: 10px;">
                                    <img 
                                    src="{{ public_path('images/pdf/exclamation.png') }}"
                                    alt="">
                                </span>
                            @endif
                            {{ $question['question'] }}
                        </td>
                        @if ($question['radio_answer'] === true)
                            <td class="td20">
                                Sim(X)
                            </td>
                        @endif
                        @if ($question['radio_answer'] === false)
                            <td class="td20">
                                Não(X)
                            </td>
                        @endif
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td100" colspan="2"> {{ $question['text_answer'] }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            @endif

        @empty
            Nenhuma questão encontrada
        @endforelse
        {{--  --}}
        <table class="tables">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Possui outro tipo de doença que não tenha sido citado a cima?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caso a resposta tenha sido sim, especifique o tipo da doença:</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Por ser verdade, firmo a presente</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>____/____/________</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="padding: 120px 0 50px">
            <tr>
                <td class="signatureNames" style="padding-bottom: 120px;">
                    <div class="signatureLines">
                    </div>
                    <span>Cirurgião Dentista / CRO</span>
                </td>
                <td class="w50"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="signatureNames">
                    <div class="signatureLines">
                    </div>
                    <span>Paciente</span>
                </td>
                @if ($data->user->responsibles && $data->user->responsibles->isNotEmpty())
                    <td class="signatureNames">
                        <div class="signatureLines">
                        </div>
                        <span>Responsável</span>
                    </td>
                @endif
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: From your errors, the errors doesn't come from the CSS. Can you share the parts of code where you are creatng the PDF (in the question itself, using the "Edit" link). If there are, please add the name of the libraries you are using

Comment: @Kaddath I will share my whole code on the bottom of the question. I am using snappyPDF and laravel blade